# Selecting the first row from the query output because of the same name or set it into variable name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use php-mysql

this is my output table on query because I use LEFT JOIN and have a null value
Query = "`Select * from table LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.ID=table2.ID`"

and the ouput is

```
ID | ID   |
1  | NULL |
```

and if I get the datas from `$row['id]` using `mysqli_fetch`
the thing that returns to me is `NULL or ""` and what I wanted to get the `value is = 1`

and I'm thinking that I'll just set the table.ID into variable but I don't know how

Comment: Because the SELECT list is returning two columns with the same name, PHP is only seeing one of them. You'd need to assign an alias to at least one of those, so they have different names, for example...  `SELECT table.id, table2.id AS t2_id FROM ...`.  (This isn't an answer, because I'm not sure whether you meant to ask a question, or  if you were just giving us a status report.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use column aliases for the `id` column in the first table from the `id` column in the second table:

```
select table.id as id1, 
       table2.id as id2
from table 
    left join table2 on table.ID=table2.ID
```

Then you can use the column alias in your php code to access that particular value.